# Expression of type '()-> is ambiguous without more context

Tags: swift, swift3

[image]

```
let lockQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.test.LockQueue")
imapSession?.connectionLogger = { (UnsafeMutableRawPointer, MCOConnectionLogType, data) -> () in
    lockQueue.sync() {
        if (type != MCOConnectionLogType.SentPrivate) {  //error is coming in this line
            //TODO: better memory management
            if let data = data {
                let errorString = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                print("event logged \(String(describing: UnsafeMutableRawPointer)) withData: \(errorString!)")
```

I have converted from swift 1.2 to swift 3.2. I changed dispatch_queue_create to latest syntax but finally facing this issue. Can anyone please suggest how I can solve this issue?

Comment: what is "`type`"?

Comment: `(UnsafeMutableRawPointer, MCOConnectionLogType, data)` => `(unsafeMutableRawPointer, type, data)` ? You need to name the var, not put their "class". You did it for `(NS)Data`, but not for the two others?

Comment: Thanks it's working

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass values / variables in the closure rather than types

```
   imapSession?.connectionLogger = { (pointer, type, data) in
```

And don't use `NSString` in Swift unless the compiler tells you to do

```
let errorString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
```